# How to read ternary relationship in ORM(Object role modeling) diagram?

Tags: object-role-modeling

I have an example of allocation `Result` below. I know how to read binary relationships but this triple box marked red in the image confuses me.

When and in what order do we read those roles after slashes inside the box : in, award of?

I assume that we can read this diagram in 3 ways:

- **First box** Student has result of Grade for Unit.
- **Second box** Grade givent to Student in Unit
- **Third box** Unit grants to Student award of Grade (**?** this one has no sense **?**)

Can we read it any more ways?

[image]

Answer (score 3):

This is not really a valid ORM diagram (as defined by Halpin), because:

1. all the fact types lack a reading (entity type names are provided instead),
2. no uniqueness constraints are shown (every fact type must have at least one uniqueness constraint),
3. role predicates are shown inside the role boxes (not an ORM practise),
4. the ternary is not shown as objectified, even though it (and the other fact types) have entity names.
5. the identifying roles must be mandatory, but this is not shown.

Here, Result is the name of an entity type. This entity type objectifies the ternary fact type, for which no name and no reading are supplied. If you wanted to name the fact type, a suitable name might be "Grading", in reference to the action in which the Result was assigned. The same problem applies to the other fact types; the creator of this diagram is confused as to the difference between a fact type and the object which may objectify that fact type. For example, the fact type "Student identify" is a noun, but the fact type (if it is to be named) should be called "Student Identification", naming the action not the objectification. Similarly for Grade award (Grade Coding), Unit identity (Unit Naming).

However, leaving aside these syntax differences, the possible intended readings for the Result fact type are "Student achieved Grade for Unit", "Grade was awarded to Student for Unit", and the like. In CQL, the objectification is indicated by saying "*each* Result *is where* some Student achieved *some* Grade for *some* Unit, *that* Grade was awarded to *that* Student for *that* Unit"

The predicate text inside the roles of the Result fact type are not well defined. The intention here is to apply these predicates to the relationship between the Result entity and the object which plays each respective role. These three binary fact types (called Link Fact Types) are not shown, but are implied by the objectification. I would suggest the following readings for these link fact types:

1. Result is awarded to Student/Student received Result
2. Result is of Grade/Grade applies to Result
3. Result is awarded for Unit/Unit received Result

Normally the link fact types and the associated readings are not shown, and the implicit readings provided by the tools are "involved in/is of", for example "Student is involved in Result", "Result is of Student". You can see why it can be better to provide custom readings instead.

I recommend you get a copy of Terry Halpin's book "Information Modeling and Relational Databases" and learn from that, because it's clear that your instructor has non-standard theory and practises.